# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error Undefined property:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ESchool\resources\views\front\index.blade.php)

and I don not  know what is wrong

this is the part of my index page where I get the error
<

```
div class="special_cource_text">
                        <a href="../../../../../../Users/Khaldoun%20Alhalabi/Desktop/etrain/course-details.html"
                            class="btn_4">{{$course->categories()->name}}</a>
```

and here my category model

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "categories"  ;
    protected $primaryKey = "id" ;
    public $timestamps = true ;
    protected $fillable =
    [
        'name' ,
    ] ;


    /**
     * Get all of the comments for the Category
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Course::class, 'foreign_key');
    }
}
```

and here my course model

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "courses"  ;
    protected $primaryKey = "id" ;
    public $timestamps = true ;
    protected $fillable =
    [
        'name' ,
        'image' ,
        'price' ,
        'small_description' ,
        'description' ,

    ] ;
  public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
    public function trainers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Trainer::class);
    }
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( Student::class );
    }
}
```

Comment: try accessing like {{$course->categories->name}}

Comment: when I do this I get this error 
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved it the problem was in the name of the foreign key I was named it as cat_id but it must be category_id
found it in the docs of laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `public function categories()` to `public function category()`
   (same for the the other functions. BelongsTo returns
   one object, so the function names should be singular)
2. I don't see a category_id in your model, but I am going to assume it is there.
3. Don't use brackets when accessing the related object's properties, just write
   `$course->category->name`

Comment: MrEvers 
thx for helping but nothing of above does work

Comment: @KhaldounAlHalabi can you list all the properties of your course model?

Comment: I solved it man thank for ur help and kindness and I posted the answer